# Is there a function to bind 'next'/'prev' incrementation into an external button, in Fullcalendar react 2022

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to bind the next/prev actions of FullCalendar, into an external function but I cannot get to increment/decrement the date, because I cannot get the syntax or maybe it is not applicable.

I have seen some code that does it with jquery but I need to do it in React 17 and in Fullcalendar version 5. I haven't found any exaples/code on how to pass that functionallity into extrnal buttons, no matter how hard I looked for it. All answers are outdated and I am trying blindly to get it to work.

```
const TimelineTab = ({events, resources, shiftData}) => {
  const ref = useRef(null)
     const someMethod = (prev) => {
      dateIncrement({ days: -1 })
    }
```

Here is my return

```
return (
    <section>
      <div className='app-user-list'>

      <button  size='12' color='primary' onClick={someMethod}>ok</button>
         
      { events[0]?.title &&
        <FullCalendar 
        ref={ref}
          schedulerLicenseKey= 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives' 
          contentHeight="auto"
          plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, daygridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
          // Controls over Calendar
          headerToolbar={{
            left: 'prev today next Cprev',
            center: 'title',
            right : 'resourceTimelineDay resourceTimelineWeek resourceTimelineMonth'
          }}
          //Initial view 
          initialView='resourceTimelineDay'
        />
      }
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
export default TimelineTab
```

So there is a button right above the fullcalendar component that has an onClick function (someMethod) which in turn must set the fullcalendar to one day before the set date.

To simplify it as posssible, I need to get the functionality of prev, next buttons in the Fullcalendar header, to an outer button.

fIs there a way to do it ?

Comment: Fullcalendar will run the `datesSet` callback whenever the date range changes (which can be for more reasons than just the buttons being pressed). But why do you want to handle this exactly? If it's for the purpose of loading new events, you should not do it this way - instead make a dynamic event feed using the events-as-json or events-as-a-function options. Everything I've mentioned above is described in the fullcalendar documentation

Comment: I need to make buttons that filter data and dropdown list of resources.  My data are dynamic. Also, things have changed in react since the documentation of v5 and I am having a hard time to find a list and a description of all methods that come with Fullcalendar.  (Thank you for your efforts Dyson, I can see you are trying to help a lot of people through all those years.)

Comment: `I am having a hard time to find a list and a description of all methods that come with Fullcalendar`...they are right there in the fullCalendar documentation and always have been: https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc. Whatever may have changed in React (I am not an expert about it), fullCalendar hasn't fundamentally changed since v5, and all methods/options will still be available via the API. Are you having a specific problem/error when you try to use anything from the options or methods?

Answer (score 2):

For React 2022 devs looking into getting the FullCalendar API outside the FullCalendar component, with no Jquery, this is how I managed to get it to work for me.

```
//FullCalendar Imports
import FullCalendar, { EventApi, Interaction } from '@fullcalendar/react'
import daygridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'

import { useRef } from 'react'
```

The main functions is as follows

```
const TimelineTab = ({ events, resources, data }) => {

  const calendarRef = useRef()

  const handleSelect = (props) => {
    //get response from FC API
    console.log('fc api says:', props)

    //Custom button to control next
    const nextHandle = () => {
      const api = calendarRef.current.getApi()
        api.next()
    }
    //Custom button to control back (previous day)
    const prevHandle = () => {
      const api = calendarRef.current.getApi()
        api.prev()
    }
    //Custom button to go to today
    const todayHandle = () => {
      const api = calendarRef.current.getApi()
      api.today()
    }
```

And this my return

```
  return (
    <section>
      <div className='app-user-list'>

                <button className="btn" onClick = {() => prevHandle()}>Prev</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick = {() => todayHandle()}>Today</button>
                <button className="btn" onClick = {() => nextHandle()}>Next</button>

        {events[0]?.title &&
          <FullCalendar
            //Needed to get FC API outside the FC
            ref={calendarRef} 
            // onSelect
            eventClick={handleSelect}
            //Licence Key!
            schedulerLicenseKey='CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives'
            //** This is for rendering the Calander when it is in a TAB **/
            contentHeight="auto"
            // plugins FullCalendar
            plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin, daygridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
            //controls over Calendar
            headerToolbar={{
              left: 'prev today next Reload',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'resourceTimelineDay resourceTimelineWeek resourceTimelineMonth'
            }}
            //initial View
            initialView='resourceTimelineDay'
            //Mapping resources
            resources={resources}
            //Mapping events
            events={events}
            //Drag n' Drop Functionallity
            selectable={[true]}
            //Timezone
            timeZone='local'
            //Calendar title
            resourceAreaHeaderContent='Users Shifts'
            //Grouping of resources
            resourceGroupField='building'
            //Initial slot duration
            slotDuration='00:30'
            //The value overriding the editable setting for this specific event
            editable={false}
            // Current time indicator
            nowIndicator
            defaultTimedEventDuration='02:30'
            resourceAreaWidth="26rem"
            eventOrderStrict={true}
            allDaySlot='true'
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            //custom Week view
            views={{
              resourceTimelineWeek: {
                type: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
                weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',
                buttonText: 'Week',
                slotDuration: '24:00',
                timeZone: 'local'
              },
              //Month
              resourceTimelineMonth: {
                type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
                buttonText: 'Month',
                slotDuration: '24:00',
                resourceAreaWidth: '20rem'
              }
            }}
          />
        }
  )
}
export default TimelineTab
```

Comment: FYI you can read about how to use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) if you're struggling to format your code and text. I've edited this one for you as you can see.